# Using the URLconf defined in crp1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns,admin/ The current path, register.html, didn't match any of these.**

Tags: django, connection

Page not found error in django.
I got 404 error   my url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/register.html and error is

> **Using the URLconf defined in crp1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:  [name='index'] register [name='register']
>   admin/ The current path, register.html, didn't match any of these.**

I created one folder for projects in that I started reglog  application in crp1 folder and index page I am getting but when I click form index.html for sign up page I get above error.
In my application url file I coded:

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
    path('register', views.register, name='register')
]
```

in views file:

```
def index(request):
     return render(request,'index.html')  
def register(request):
    return render(request,'register.html')
```

and in my project name crp1 file I write following code in crp1.urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('reglog.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)'
]
```

and in register.html

```
<a href="register.html"></a>
```

Comment: The correct url is probably http://127.0.0.1:8000/register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access `127.0.0.1:8000/register` (without the `.html`)

or change the link to

`<a href="/register"></a>`

Comment: thank friend ...now its working... but what  problem